# Android LCD Broken, Screen Locked, Device Unauthorized

Tags: lock-screens, broken-screen

I have an Android device whose LCD is broken. The unit functions and receives call, messages and gives the usual audio notifications.

However, in order to synch back data, I need to access the main memory.
However, the screen is locked via a pattern.  ADB does see the device, but as unauthorised.

Also:

```
macbopr: adb shell rm /data/system/gesture.key
error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
```

How can I overcome this block?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to unlock the screen, you can use the `adb shell input` command.

[This link](https://github.com/mattwilson1024/android-pattern-unlock/blob/master/unlock.sh) is a script that you could modify.  I haven't tried it myself, but it looks like it should work.  You'll have to tweek it for your specific device, and enter in your password.

Comment: the `adb shell input`command leads to the same error: device unauthorised error.    are your two paragraphs related?

Comment: The script runs the adb shell input command multiple times.  So yes, they would be related.  Would something like this work?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36507415/3893224 I've really only done this with devices that I already gave permission on, or on rooted devices.

Comment: I believe I had rooted this phone, but why would I trust my memory ?! I also think I activated USB debugging, but that too is prone to memory leaks...  Rebooting into recovery mode does not change any behaviour... still seen as unauthorised.